# Print string from 2 dimensional character array

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, printf

I've looked around and tried different syntax's for this but I can't seem to get it to work. I know this is elementary, but it's something that shouldn't take too long to figure out.

I have the character array...

```
char *roster[2][14] = {
      {"13", "10", "24", "25", "15", "1", "00", "4", "11", "23", "22", "32", "3", "35"},
      {"Isaiah Briscoe", "Jonny David", "EJ Floreal", "Dominique Hawkins", "Isaac Humphries", "Skal Labissiere", "Marcus Lee", "Charles Matthews", "Mychal Mulder", "Jamal Murray", "Alex Poythress", "Dillon Pulliam", "Tyler Ulis", "Derrick Willis"}
    };
```

Then I'm generating a random element from that array...

```
random = rand() % 14;
printf("What is %s 's number?", roster[2][random]);
```

Then I try to print it out, but it fails...

```
printf("What is %s 's number?", roster[2][random]);
```

It outputs

```
What is (null) 's number?
```

and lldb shows that the printf statement jumps into...

```
libsystem_c.dylib`strlen:
->  0x7fff9a596d32 <+18>: pcmpeqb (%rdi), %xmm0
    0x7fff9a596d36 <+22>: pmovmskb %xmm0, %esi
    0x7fff9a596d3a <+26>: andq   $0xf, %rcx
    0x7fff9a596d3e <+30>: orq    $-0x1, %rax
```

Comment: Fails how? Whats the output?

Comment: `random` is a well known system function name, defined in stdlib.h.  It is a bad idea to declare a variable name the same as a system function name.

Answer (score 2):

Array index starts from `0`.

For `char *roster[2][14];`, the possible indices are

```
roster[0][random];
roster[1][random];
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in c start at 0, so if you declare:

```
char *roster[2]
```

Then you can only reference roster[0] and roster[1].

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("What is %s 's number?", roster[2][random]);
```

You access index out of bound invoking ***undefined behaviour*** .

Because you can have indices `roster[0][random] and roster[1][random]` **not** `roster[2][random]` because it is declared as -

```
char *roster[2][14] = {
  {"13", "10", "24", "25", "15", "1", "00", "4", "11", "23", "22", "32", "3", "35"},
  {"Isaiah Briscoe", "Jonny David", "EJ Floreal", "Dominique Hawkins", "Isaac Humphries", "Skal Labissiere", "Marcus Lee", "Charles Matthews", "Mychal Mulder", "Jamal Murray", "Alex Poythress", "Dillon Pulliam", "Tyler Ulis", "Derrick Willis"}
};
```

You can print these -

```
printf("What is %s 's number?", roster[1][random]);
```

Or -

```
printf("What is %s 's number?", roster[0][random]);
```